# How to import modules or external .js files in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, tensorflow.js

I would like to use tensorflow.js in my node application.

The example here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/universal-sentence-encoder

states:

Installation

$ npm install @tensorflow/tfjs @tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder

Usage
To import in npm:

```
import * as use from '@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder';
```

or as a standalone script tag:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder"></script>
```

If I add the script tags to a html file (without node.js) my code works if i execute it within script tags in that same html file.

But i don't know how I can import the functionality into my node application (the .js file running express)

Do I need to "require" something, because "import..." doesn't work

I hope you can help me, kind regards,
mg

Comment: Yes, you need `require` because `import` won't work in Nodejs. The reason being, `import` is ES6 module syntax but Nodejs works on CommonJS.

Answer (score 0):

- In node, you can use the following to load the `universal-sentence-encoder`

```js
const use = require('@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder');
```

- Starting with node.js 13 (experimental), it will be possible to use es6 import in node.js. But the file should have its nearest parent package.json `type` set to `module`.
- You can use es6 import syntax if you use ts-node TypeScript execution environment for node.js. But you would need to supply the ts.config.json indicating that you are loading a common.js module.

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "out",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*",
                "src/types/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```